# Making a more efficient SP based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following stored procs and I want to make it more efficient. When p_training is not null I get more records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetAssets
    @p_language VARVHAR(1) = 'E',
    @p_training BIT = NULL

AS
  IF (@p_training IS NOT NULL)
    SELECT Asset_Key AS CodeId,
           CASE WHEN @p_language = 'E' THEN HRMS_Desc_Eng
                WHEN @p_language = 'F' THEN HRMS_Desc_Fre
           END AS CodeName
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Asset_Type NOT IN ('C')
    ORDER BY CodeName
  ELSE
    SELECT Asset_Key AS CodeId,
           CASE WHEN @p_language = 'E' THEN HRMS_Desc_Eng
                WHEN @p_language = 'F' THEN HRMS_Desc_Fre
           END AS CodeName
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Asset_Type NOT IN ('C')
    AND (LocationId < 2000 OR LocationId > 2030)
    ORDER BY CodeName
```

How can I make it more efficient or remove the if statement if possible?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Aside from indexes and maybe getting rid of the OR condition this is as efficient as you can get.

Comment: What you have here is multiple execution paths. There are some serious performance issues with this type of approach the way you have it coded here. Please read this article which explains how to deal with this type of situation. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: JonH, thank you for your input. The initial SP had an if statement for four different languages and I reduce it with the CASE statement. I was wondering if I could reduce it to remove more code duplicate. I think that was more my concern, however I appreciate the fact you looked at it. @Sean thanks for the link, pretty interesting. I bookmark that article :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code duplication can be reduced by checking whether `@p_training` is not null in the where clause instead of using `IF`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetAssets
    @p_language VARVHAR(1) = 'E',
    @p_training BIT NULL    
AS
    SELECT Asset_Key AS CodeId,
           CASE WHEN @p_language = 'E' THEN HRMS_Desc_Eng
                WHEN @p_language = 'F' THEN HRMS_Desc_Fre
           END AS CodeName
    FROM Assets
    WHERE Asset_Type NOT IN ('C')
    AND (LocationId < 2000 OR LocationId > 2030 OR @p_training IS NOT NULL)
    ORDER BY CodeName
```

But this won't make the query more efficient.

Comment: This is a sacrifice on performance though...you are dealing with boolean logic now.  You could explicitly check the location and handle in if/else rather than boolean logic, but hardly will this improve any better.

Comment: Thank you TI, this is what I was looking for. Like JonH stated it do not help efficiency but reduce code duplication. The initial SP was so huge that I had no option at that point. I will mark both of you suggestion as the answer if I can.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is truly a concern, the best way is to split your original `Stored Procedure` into 2:

First SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAssetsNotNull
@p_language VARVHAR(1) = 'E'

AS
SELECT Asset_Key AS CodeId,
       CASE WHEN @p_language = 'E' THEN HRMS_Desc_Eng
            WHEN @p_language = 'F' THEN HRMS_Desc_Fre
       END AS CodeName
FROM Assets
WHERE Asset_Type NOT IN ('C')
ORDER BY CodeName
```

Second SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAssetsNull
@p_language VARVHAR(1) = 'E'
AS
SELECT Asset_Key AS CodeId,
       CASE WHEN @p_language = 'E' THEN HRMS_Desc_Eng
            WHEN @p_language = 'F' THEN HRMS_Desc_Fre
       END AS CodeName
FROM Assets
WHERE Asset_Type NOT IN ('C')
AND (LocationId < 2000 OR LocationId > 2030)
ORDER BY CodeName
```

Then finally, you only call the SP based on the parameter:

```
IF @p_training IS NOT NULL
EXEC GetAssetsNotNull
ELSE
EXEC GetAssetsNull
```

Edited: The last part can be done either on the Application side or the SP itself.

Comment: C.J. Thank you for your suggestion. I have over 100 SP's to revisit and I will use that approach in the future for sure :)